# How to interpret the set of simpler algorithms of ObservableHq as an reusable library?

Tags: code-reuse

The main source of [D3js](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki) solutions is `observableHq.com`, but seems **impossible** (?) to reuse algorithms by copy/paste... Is it? Even checking tutorials [like this](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-web-applications-with-d3-observable-d5c53467ff12), there are no **simple way** (with less plugins or programmer's time-consumtion!) to check and **reuse**.

Example: I need a fresh 2020 *D3js v5* algorithm for indented-tree visualization, and there are a good solution: [observableHq.com/@d3/indented-tree](https://observableHq.com/@d3/indented-tree). 
The download is not useful because is based on **complex** *Runtime class*...

But, seems a simple chart-builder algorithm,

```js
chart = {  // the indented-tree algorithm
  const nodes = root.descendants();
  const svg = d3.create("svg")// ...
  // ...
  return svg.node();
}
```

Can I, by simple human step-by-step,  convert it in a simple HTML, with no complex adaptations, that starts with `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>` and ends with no *Runtime class* use?

---

### FAQ

Aleatory questions  and answers:

> *Could you explain what the problem is with including the D3 script tag and using Runtime library in the code?*

**When** the original ObservableHq algorithm is simple, I need another way, **a simple way** to reuse it, by copy/paste and minimal adaptations.

> *Did you read the [Downloading and embedding notebooks tutorial](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/downloading-and-embedding-notebooks)?*

Yes, no news there: no "human instruction" about how to reuse code... Only "install it" and "install that". No instructions about "copy/paste and minimal adaptations" that I explained above.